# .NET & CreateObject, whose memory does the COM object use?

Tags: vb.net, excel, memory, com

I have a VB.NET application that uses CreateObject to use Excel and dump a lot of data into it. We are getting out of memory exceptions and our app is generally hitting 1GB of memory at this point. However I can't make all the numbers add up.

This is how the data is passed to Excel:

```
    worksheet_object.Range("A1").Resize(rows, cols).Value = an_array
```

The app is around 400mb with the data on screen (datagrid), when it crashes it has used an additional 600mb despite the fact that Excel with the CSV is only 200mb and the CSV is only 68mb. I realise the in memory array could be somewhat larger but how does 600mb get gobbled up passing the data to Excel unless Excel is somehow using my apps memory?

I have tried to find out if Excel via CreateObject runs in its own memory space or using my apps memory space, drew a complete blank. ProcessExplorer shows them as separate processes so I don't know what to think.

We found running the app as 64-bit rather than 32 solved the problem, but not all our clients will have 64-bit office.

So my question is this: How can that one line use 600mb and is there a better way to pass the data to Excel.

Comment: Excel only allocates memory in its own process.  You'll need to pay attention to the GC in your process and see if it is collecting often enough.  Pretty easy to never trigger a collection when you are only making interop calls.  That can get the RCWs to build up.  Use Perfmon.exe to look at the .NET GC performance counters, a memory profiler is best.  Countermeasure is to force a GC periodically, say every N rows.

Comment: You don't say how may rows and columns? (Each Excel cell can use a lot of memory). But maybe you are fragmenting the available 2GB address space: have you tried working in smaller chunks?

Comment: About 200,000 rows, maybe 50 columns. The array being passed has some 9.7 million cells. I couldn't find a means to get its in-memory size. I suppose I could use a binary seralizer and write it to a file.

Comment: Presumably this operation means making a lot of copies of the array. A worksheet of that size takes over 200MB (assuming its only numbers): the equivalent object array is probably about the same and then going through com-interop probably implies at least one or maybe 2 more copies in memory. memory fragmentation can mean that requests for large contiguous chunks of memory cannot be met. It would probably work in 32-bit mode if you did it using 10 smaller chunks

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that this takes some time to run the 1 line as well, 9.7M cells!?  But anyway, 2 questions:

1: How can that one line use 600mb (I assume you mean MB (Byte), not mb (bit))

I think you answered that with 9.7M cells. Thats only 61 Bytes per cell. I would assume you have some strings.  Each string uses a couple bytes, plus 2 Bytes for every character in the cell. Numbers with a decimal point, they take up 16 Bytes.. period. Not to mention, the array has some size to it, to handle it's information. See this chart for an idea of what the data takes up in VB. [2012 VB Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) One amazing thing that I just learned because I had not looked at this chart in so long, is that by going to 64bit OS, it should have actually taken MORE memory. Luckily, 64bit can handle more.

2: Is there a better way to pass the data to Excel.

You might try using the OLEDB ACE driver to work with your excel file.  It is faster and does not require EXCEL to be installed on the computer, big pluses there.

[How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934)

This post is old but still relevant and very helpfull. For connection strings for newer versions of excel, try [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: We ended up taking the 64-bit route for this client but I think this is an issue that will hit us again so the links should be quite useful for looking at solutions. Thanks.